# React app on sub folder

Tags: reactjs

I have created a react app with `create-react-app` in a subfolder of my project. Url of current app is `http://app.local` and url of react app is `http://app.local/v2`.

What i want is when i run `npm start` a browser window should open from `http://app.local/v2` instead of `http://localhost:3000` and when i run `npm build` the paths should be point to the relative directory.

I already tried `basename` and `start_url` parameters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create React App builds your app to be hosted at the server root by default.

To change this behavior, set the `homepage` in your package.json, like this:

```
{
...
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/subdirectory",
...
}
```